# MySQL Changing the Name of GROUP BY Column in a View Doesn't Return Results Properly

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I have an issue with a View in my MySQL Database. When I select the view, and run a WHERE clause on it, I can only use the direct name of the column, and cannot change it to something else using AS - otherwise the content does not get displayed right:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED VIEW `View_Donations` AS
select
    concat('$', sum(`donators_animal_linking`.`donation_amount`)) AS 
    `Donation Total`,
    `donators_animal_linking`.`animal_type` AS `animal_type`
from
    `donators_animal_linking`
group by
    `donators_animal_linking`.`animal_type`

SELECT * FROM View_Donations
WHERE 'Animal Type' IS NOT NULL;
```

[image: Receiving all Data regardless of the WHERE clausew]

Even when the WHERE clause is set to IS NOT NULL, the null data still gets shown. And when it's set to something like 'Animal Type' === 'dolphin', then nothing shows up. Am I able to change the column name, or should I just leave it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong kind of quotes in your `'Animal Type'`. The engine considers it a string, not a name of a column.

Which is why `IS NOT NULL` is always `true` (`Animal Type` is a well-defined string, so it's not null).

And `'Animal Type' = 'dolphin'` will be always false, because - obviously - the two strings are different. Use backticks, like you do above.